# Does "ng" sound at all like "Angular"?

Tags: pronunciation

I've started working with the AngularJS web development framework, and the first question in [their FAQ](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq) is this:

> Why is this project called "AngularJS"? Why is the namespace called "ng"?
>   Because HTML has Angular brackets and "ng" sounds like "Angular".

To me, "ng" doesn't sound anything like "Angular". Is this a regional thing, or are these people just mad?

Comment: With with exception of some Vietnamese surnames (where it is typically anglicized as "*Eng*"), I've never seen "ng" as a stand-alone phoneme, so I don't know "how *ng* sounds". That said, my *instinct* would be to pronounce it as it is pronounced in *angular*, sans the *a* (or, equivalently, as in the suffix *-ing*, sans the *i*).

Comment: Because Angular's approach is ***n***o ***g***ood.

Comment: Generally, uncompounded `NG` letter combinations in English are pronounced **either** as the velar nasal phoneme /ŋ/, as in _singer_ /'sɪŋər/, **or** as the velar nasal-stop cluster /ŋɡ/ as in _finger_ /'fɪŋɡər/. Note that it looks like they rhyme, but in fact they don't.

Comment: @JohnLawler: I don't know if you're versed in Vietnamese, but if you are I'm curious about what their "ng" sound really is. When Vietnamese people pronounce names like *Nguyen* it sounds to my ear like the barest hint of *ng* followed by *w*.

Comment: Viet `NG` is its phoneme /ŋ/, which -- like all consonants -- is perfectly normal to pronounce at the beginning of a word, although it's not in English. If you stretch out the nasal at the center of _singer_ and then insert a slight pause in the middle, keeping your mouth in the same places, you'll wind up saying "sing ... nger", with the second syllable beginning with /ŋ/. Practice and it's easy to do. If you can do it with /m/ and /n/, you can do it with /ŋ/. They're just the nasal versions of /b/, /d,/ and /ɡ/, with the mouth stopped but the nose open for release.

Comment: @Robusto. Nguyễn (thus the correct spelling) has an initial consonant /ŋ/, an /u/ on-glide, main vowel /i/, /ɜ/ off-glide, final consonant /n/, and a dipping, strangulated tone.

Comment: I've only worked in that domain a little, but I've always pronounced it "en gee", or, very occasionally, "nig".

Comment: @JohnLawler My wife would disagree about singer and finger not rhyming.  In her accent (Cheshire/Staffordshire) the g in singer is definitely pronounced.

Comment: It's pronounced in some Long Gisland dialects, too. But not usually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's poorly worded in the FAQ.  What they mean is just that they've used the first two consonant sounds in "Angular" as the prefix for their codes.

Comment: This would be my guess, too. A better (assuming it'd be correct) answer might be, *We named it* Angular *after the angular brackets used in HTML. We pronounce* ng *like* ang *in* angular.